# How can I use NSArray and NSDictionary with this SQL data?

Tags: sql, swift, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

Couldn't parse JSON data.

Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' (0x10f02fc08) to 'NSMutableArray' (0x10f02fcd0).

JSON data [here](http://alicelik.me/forios/service.php) and code here;

```
echo json_encode($resultArray);
```

And here is my trial code;

```
func parseJSON() {
    var jsonResult: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    do{
        jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: self.data as Data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSMutableArray
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }

    var jsonElement: NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
    let locations: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    for i in 1...jsonResult.count
    {
        jsonElement = jsonResult[i-1] as! NSDictionary

        let location = LocationModel()

        if let name = jsonElement["Name"] as? String,
            let address = jsonElement["Address"] as? String,
            let latitude = jsonElement["Latitude"] as? String,
            let longitude = jsonElement["Longitude"] as? String
        {
            location.name = name
            location.address = address
            location.latitude = latitude
            location.longitude = longitude

        }
        locations.add(location)
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in

        self.delegate.itemsDownloaded(items: locations)

    })
}
```

Comment: Why are you using NSDictionary, NSArray, etc. in Swift?

Comment: @Ali Hi. I'm sorry but your question is still very unclear. May I suggest that if you're not sure how to search on SO you can start by browsing [my JSON answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a2227743%20json)? There's quite a lot, and with all the related links it should give you enough material to solve your problem - or to be able to better explain your issue after some reading. Good luck!

Comment: @EricAya im on something let me update like 5 min

Comment: @Ali Sure. Take as much time as needed.

Comment: @EricAya wow i did it. i will update here. My grammer is bad. Maybe that's why I couldn't ask the right question.

Comment: @Ali Great news! :) Don't be afraid about your grammar, just write your answer as clearly as you can, it will be useful for other users who struggle the same way you did.

Comment: Thank you so much @EricAya your comments inspire me. And you was right, I'll develop myself about to ask more open questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: IT WILL FIX [THIS](http://codewithchris.com/iphone-app-connect-to-mysql-database/#creatingphpservice)

instead of:

```
var jsonResult: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
```

do this:

```
var jsonResult: NSArray = NSArray()
```

and instead of:

```
jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: self.data as Data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSMutableArray
```

do this:

```
jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: self.data as Data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSArray
```

full code:

```
func parseJSON() {
    var jsonResult: NSArray = NSArray()
    do{
        jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: self.data as Data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSArray
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }

    var jsonElement: NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
    let locations: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    for i in 1...jsonResult.count
    {
        jsonElement = jsonResult[i-1] as! NSDictionary

        let location = LocationModel()

        if let name = jsonElement["Name"] as? String,
            let address = jsonElement["Address"] as? String,
            let latitude = jsonElement["Latitude"] as? String,
            let longitude = jsonElement["Longitude"] as? String
        {

            location.name = name
            location.address = address
            location.latitude = latitude
            location.longitude = longitude

        }

        locations.add(location)

    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in

        self.delegate.itemsDownloaded(items: locations)

    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `JSONSerialization` is returning a non-mutable array, and you can't just cast a `NSArray` to a `NSMutableArray`. Instead, just declare it to be `NSArray`:

```
func parseJSON() {
    var jsonResult: NSArray

    do {
        jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data as Data) as! NSArray
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
        return
    }

    ...
}
```

Or, alternatively, use Swift's native collection types rather than falling back on old `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` types:

```
func parseJSON() {
    var jsonResult: [[String: Any]]  // this is an array of dictionaries

    do {
        jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data as Data) as! [[String: Any]]
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
        return
    }

    for jsonElement in jsonResult {            
        if let name = jsonElement["Name"] as? String,
            let address = jsonElement["Address"] as? String,
            let latitude = jsonElement["Latitude"] as? String,
            let longitude = jsonElement["Longitude"] as? String
        {
            let location = LocationModel()
            location.name = name
            location.address = address
            location.latitude = latitude
            location.longitude = longitude
            locations.add(location) // or, if you defined `locations` to be a Swift array, `locations.append(location)`
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

(Personally, I'd probably also define the `data` to be a `Data` rather than a `NSData` and define `locations` to be `[LocationModel]` rather than `NSMutableArray`.)